# Removing an item from a WPF binding listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, listbox, itemssource

I have a WPF application with a ListBox (called listMyItems) which is successfully bound to a class of MyItems that I created. I have a List of MyItems called currentMyItems which is then assigned as ItemSource to the ListBox. It all works fine, if I add an item to the currentMyItems it pops up on the list, etc.
The problem occurs when I try to remove the selected item in the ListBox. This is the code that I use:

```
currentMyItems.Remove((MyItem)listMyItems.SelectedItem);
```

The item disappears from the ListBox but the next time I update it, it pops back up as it was never deleted. Any tips?

Comment: `but the next time I update it` what does this exactly mean? Are you repopulating the list?

Comment: Yes, I'm dynamically adding items to it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you may be confused about how data binding works. When you bind a property, you are telling WPF to go look somewhere else for the value of that property.

When you bind the `ListBox.ItemsSource` property to `currentMyItems`, you are telling WPF to go look at the `currentMyItems` list to find its list of items. If `currentMyItems` is an `ObservableCollection` instead of a `List<T>`, then the UI will automatically receive a notification to update the bound value when you add or remove an item from the collection.

Based on what you say in the question, it sounds like you you have two collections, one of which is bound, and the other which is used to recreate the first collection anytime a change occurs. All that is not needed.

Just create one `ObservableCollection<MyItem>`, bind it to the `ListBox.ItemsSource` property, and then add or remove items from that single collection. It should work as you would expect.

```
<ListBox x:Name="listMyItems" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" />
```

and

```
MyItems.Add((MyItem)listMyItems.SelectedItem)
MyItems.Remove((MyItem)listMyItems.SelectedItem)
```

If you're interested, I also have some beginner articles on my blog for WPF users who are struggling to understand the DataContext. You may want to check out [Understanding the change in mindset when switching from WinForms to WPF](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/10/12/switching-from-winforms-to-wpfmvvm/) and [What is this “DataContext” you speak of?](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/)

Comment: Updating the `MyItems` collection doesn't seem to be all you need to do. It will work for the 1st ListBox, but what if you want to update a 2nd ListBox, using the `.SelectedItem` of the 1st ListBox?  Doing `MySelectedItems.Add((MyItem)listMyItems.SelectedItem)` doesn't update that box automatically.  I've heard people use the refrain "implement INotifyPropertyChanged" but not say how.  Simply adding it like this: `public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged` at the top is not enough.  How does updating an `ObservableCollection<MyItem>` update a ListBox? Missing piece here.

Comment: Never mind - I figured it out.  You have to set your `.ItemsSource` of the 2nd box to that 2nd `ObservableCollection<MyItem>` you create.  Once you do, it updates automatically.  If you never set the `.ItemsSource` property in the code-behind, even if you do it in the XAML markup, it doesn't make the changes.

Answer (score 3):

If you bound it correctly to an ObservableCollection and currentMyItems is that collection. Than it means that you must have reloaded currentMyItems in meantime.

Also consider binding the SelectedItem property of your ListView - your view model doesn't have to know about the view at all.

Comment: +1 for the recommendation of binding `SelectedItem` as well to keep the View and ViewModel layers separate

Answer (score 2):

Your source collection must be modufy (inherit from IList or ICollection). If your source collection does not support this method of your interface Remove, you can't remove item from source.

So, when you want to remove item you must cast ItemsSource to IList or ICollection:

```
var source = listbox.ItemsSource as IList ?? listbox.ItemsSource as ICollection;
```

and then check:

```
if (source == null) return;
```

then:

```
listbox.SelectedItems.ForEach(source.Remove);
listbox.Items.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the `currentMyItems<MyItem>` an   `ObservableColection<MyItem>`. This way it will raise a property change whenever modified and the UI gets updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

By using ObservableCollection you will automatically get updates on the UI.

You should use an ObservableCollection instead of List.
A good thing is to always use ObservableCollection instead of List when something to do with UI