# C#: Deleting a ListBox item

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a ListBox with a databinding to a BindingList. Everything works fine (displaying data, adding an item,...) except of deleting the selected item. I don't know how to do this and hope you could help me. For me multiple selection is not necessary.
PS: I use C# and WPF.

ListBox:

```
    <ListBox x:Name="listBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="183.784" BorderThickness="0" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=i}" FontSize="15"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

List:

```
    public class SampleClass
    {
        public string i { get; set; }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingList<SampleClass> SampleList = new BindingList<SampleClass>();
        SampleList.Add(new SampleClass() { i = "ABC" });
        listBox1.ItemsSource = SampleList;
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing an item from a WPF binding listbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937927/removing-an-item-from-a-wpf-binding-listbox)

Comment: Have you tried setting the AllowRemove property of BindingList to true? Default is always true, but maybe you should try to fetch the property value and see if its being set as false somewhere?